# Cómo obtener value del botón submit al enviar formulario

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Actualmente para reutilizar el código de cada formulario estoy usando:

```
$('.formulario').submit(function(e){
            var value = $(this).val()
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                bootbox.alert(data.mensaje);
            });
        });
```

El problema es que cada botón `submit` tienen un `value`, que me servirá para identificar las secciones debido a que son varios formularios.

¿Cómo podría enviar los formularios y obtener el `value` del botón `submit` que forma parte de él?

Answer (score 4):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo

```js
$('.formulario').submit(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
            //Buscar el input de tipo submit. Ojo aqui porque puede fallar si no se controla.
            var submitValue = $(e.target).find('input[type=submit]')[0].name
             
            //Añadimos los valores. Mira serializeArray puede que te sea mas util. 
            var datos = `${$(this).serialize()}&desde=${submitValue}`
            
            $.post($(this).attr('action'), datos, function(data){
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                bootbox.alert(data.mensaje);
            });
  
          alert(datos)
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  
  <form class="formulario">
      
    <input name="usuario" />
    <input name="email" />

    <input type="submit" name="registro" value="registro" />
  </form>
  
    <form class="formulario">
      
    <input name="password" />
     <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" />

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para recoger el value del botón, tendrías que hacer e.target. Target recoge el elemento que lanzó el evento, en este caso tu botón de submit. Quedaría algo como:

```
var value = e.target.value;
```

No sé cómo lo tienes montado, pero creo que igual tendría sentido darle el identificador al formulario, no al botón, y pasarle a la función del sumbit el identificador del formulario, como:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="enviarFormulario("formularioEjemplo");">
```